# NTFS ADS separator (':') in file name is forbidden

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using **primefaces 12.0.0** fileUpload component and sometimes I see in the log file the following exception :

```
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NTFS ADS separator (':') in file name is forbidden.
    javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NTFS ADS separator (':') in file name is forbidden.
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:291)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:65)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1330)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:77)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at com.shl.AjaxTimeoutFilter.doFilter(AjaxTimeoutFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NTFS ADS separator (':') in file name is forbidden.
        at org.primefaces.shaded.commons.io.FilenameUtils.indexOfExtension(FilenameUtils.java:737)
        at org.primefaces.shaded.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getExtension(FilenameUtils.java:1057)
        at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.getValidFilename(FileUploadUtils.java:91)
        at org.primefaces.model.file.CommonsUploadedFile.getFileName(CommonsUploadedFile.java:57)
        at org.primefaces.model.file.UploadedFileWrapper.getFileName(UploadedFileWrapper.java:85)
        at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.isValidType(FileUploadUtils.java:147)
        at org.primefaces.util.FileUploadUtils.tryValidateFile(FileUploadUtils.java:309)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.validateValue(FileUpload.java:86)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1040)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1341)
        at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:757)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:631)
        at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1736)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:395)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1747)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:423)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:284)
```

How to avoid this error ?

Comment: Please [report](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues) this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is running on Windows.  This error comes from Commons IO FilenameUtils...

https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.java#L951-L957

```java
if (isSystemWindows()) {
    // Special handling for NTFS ADS: Don't accept colon in the fileName.
    final int offset = fileName.indexOf(':', getAdsCriticalOffset(fileName));
    if (offset != -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("NTFS ADS separator (':') in file name is forbidden.");
    }
}
```

It looks like you are trying to pass some kind of file with a colon in the name  which is not valid on Windows according to that...

Comment: It looks like the file was uploaded

Comment: Are you sure he is just saying he is seeing these in his logs not that the file was uploaded successfully. Almost sounds like someone on a Unix file system with a ":" is uploading files to his server running Windows.

Comment: @Melloware is there's a way to configure Commons IO to replace illegal characters with underscore, or configure the fileupload component to show an error to the user that the file name contains an illegal character : please rename it ? or maybe a client side function to rename the file before uploading it to server ?

Comment: Yes open a ticket at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues that should be bubbling out not as an IllegalArgumentException but as a FacesException which would theoretically be caught and shown an error on screen if you are using a FacesExceptionHandler.

Comment: Wait it is throwing `javax.faces.FacesException` it looks like you don't use any kind of Exceptionhandler?  this should be being caught and handled properly by your app?

Comment: @Melloware, is there's a way to replace the : with _ in the file name from the primefaces fileupload component before the file gets uploaded to the server ?

Comment: I am not sure that would fix anything though?